# What is the standard image size(s) for facebook (corporate page), twitter and youTube?

Tags: website-design, facebook, images, twitter, youtube

I am going to employ the services of a graphic designer, to create logos/ images for my website for the following sites:

- Facebook (corporate page)
- Twitter  (twitter account for the business)
- YouTube  (youtube channel for the business)

I can't seem to find a consensus view on what image sizes are required, or if I can use one image size for all three websites.

Does anyone know the answer, or can someone point me to where I can find this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upload pretty much any size you want and the services will resize to suit (what they can resize to is listed below).

Facebook: The max is 540px high by 180px wide.

Twitter: Has 2 - 73x73 px and  48x48 px. You can also see the image full size by clicking on it in a users profile.

Youtube: Is 88x88 px.

**edit**

Thanks to [DisgruntledGoat](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/233/disgruntledgoat) for the comment, I have edited it with his additions.

Comment: All the services allow you to upload larger images which are then resized for you. And Twitter allows users to view the full size image.